# Why is `import axios from "axios";` causing Jest to fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs

I have the following

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
...
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
...
function App() {
}
```

Everything runs fine but when I try to run the tests I get...

```
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       5 | import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
       6 | import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
    >  7 | import axios from "axios";
         | ^
```

If I remove the Axios code everything works fine, so why does it fail with the import?

Comment: please provide some more info to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this update your test command in your package.json to this : `"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!axios)/'",`. This error is because axios changed their module type from CommonJS TO ECMAScript in their v1.x.x and higher.

Comment: Interesting any idea what to do similarly in vue because I get the same thing there